# One Year Multiple Entry Schengen Visa

Tags: schengen-visas, spain, pakistani-citizens, multiple-entry, long-stay-visas

I am applying for the 4th time for a Schengen Visa, in my previous visits I've applied for a "One year Multiple Entry Visa" by entering 90 days in:

> section: "25. Duration of the intended stay or transit Indicate the
>   number of days"

but they have not given me a long duration validation visa.
Kindly tell am I filling something wrong in the Visa Form or they are doing it deliberately? 
I have an invitation letter from my company in which it is clearly mentioned to issue One Year Multiple Entry Business Visa.

Comment: Have they refused your application(s) outright, or just given you a single entry visa(s)? What justification are you providing to explain why you need a multiple entry visa?

Comment: No they have not refused my any application , and I've got multiple entry visa as well! But it's validation was not more than 4 months.

Comment: My company clearly mentioned in the invitation letter that Along this year and next 2019 he will travel on several times to Spain and to others countries which are included in the Schengen area with the purpose of attend to several meetings with Customer.

Comment: Were these travel plans presented as a fixed itinerary with dates, locations, travel reservations etc? I agree with @Henrik’s reply, it looks like you’ve not presented sufficient justification for a one year validity period.

Answer (score 8):

(This started out as a comment, but it got rather long, and I wanted to add more)

The embassy/consulate who issues visa are free to issue them with whatever validity period they like. If you haven't provided arguments for why you should get more than (e.g.) a week (I'm not sure Schengen visa can be that short) they might (and have the right to do so) think that one year is excessive.

Even though you and the company you work for might think it would be nice to get a visa with a long period of validity, you don't decide. The only thing you can do is build a history of not violating the terms of your visas (or the laws of the countries you visit).

Whatever you write is probably taken as an indication that they should look closely before issuing a visa with shorter validity as it might conflict with your plans. If you have reasonable plans but they misread a date, they might end up thinking a 30 day visa is sufficient, but if you've written that 32 days are needed, they might look over your plans again and discover their error.

It's typical to see that people who apply several times, gradually get visas with longer validity, but if they have you on record for applying for visas with longer validity than needed, that might make them less likely to do that.

It all also depends on where you come from.

Comment: A Schengen visa can certainly be issued for a week.  The visa code specifies that visas be issued with an extra "period of grace," but this appears to be overlooked with some frequency, at least by some countries' consulates, judging by some of the questions we've seen on this site.

Comment: Kindly tell what should I write in field 25 of visa form 90 or 365 Days ?

Comment: You should write the number of days you have plans for.

Comment: +1 However note the German embassy in DC gave me a Schengen visa valid for only five days in 2005. Unbelievably rigid protocol.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are three factors to getting the visa you want.

- Many brief visits in a short period of time, so that it would be tedious **for you and for them** to apply each time. 
  If you intend to stay 90 days in one visit, it would be reasonable for you to provide the details for that one visit.
- A previous travel history without overstays.
- A solid financial and job situation which makes it appear likely that you will leave again each time.

You do not get a 90/180 visa simply because you ask for it. You get it because you fit the profile for it.

Comment: `so that it would be tedious for you **and for them** to apply each time` Tedious for the applicant, never for the consular officers. The UK government for example [makes millions on visa application fees](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2017/sep/01/home-office-makes-800-profit-on-some-visa-applications). `For example, since April the fee to apply for indefinite leave to enter for a vulnerable adult dependent relative has been set at £3,250. Its costs the Home Office £423 to process the application.`

Comment: @MusoniusRufus, we're talking about Schengen visa here. Those are not high enough to make much profit.